# Policy about link as answer

Tags: discussion, links

This question is about this one : [Clear "view history" on YouTube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/youtube-clear-history)

The current answer is quite correct but annoys me a little.
It is :

> [YouTube Help](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57714) has a solution on this.

It seem that the linked page answers the question. But the answer doesn't really answer the question, it's the link that answers.
Should the user copy the relevant information from the youtube help in its answer and maybe give the link as source or for "more information" ?

Answer (score 13):

Yes the answer should give the information and use the link as the reference/source.

Add a comment asking for more information.

Explain that it's better to quote the relevant information from the page - as long as it's not too long - as:

a) it means that all the information is available in one place

b) it guards against "link rot"

If there's no other text to explain the link at all then consider down-voting - but I'd only do that as a last resort.

Comment: I'd add a comment first and hope that the user or a moderator (or a user with enough reputation) will modify the answer with details about the link. I know I've answered with a link a few times, but often it was because the solution was lengthy.

Comment: Watch out for copyright violations though! Someone complained about my SU posts violating them. Though unless someone complains, I tend to 'quote' the articles **with attribution!**

Comment: @Ivo - Yes, always indicate that you are quoting and give attribution.

Comment: @GoodEnough - In the cases where I haven't quoted it has been due to length and I've mentioned that as the reason.